# Namespace after adding a new folder in views?

Tags: laravel, namespaces

I am new to Laravel and I have added a new folder in `Views` by the name "Layouts". The problem now is that in the controller I am trying to add the namespace using the `use` statement but somehow the view in question is not being displayed and an error `view not found` is being thrown.

`use` statement:
`use \resources\views\layouts;`

```
class dependencyController extends Controller
{ 
    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view("masterLayout");
    }
}
```

But when I mention the name of the folder in the the `dashboard` method, things work just fine.

```
public function dashboard()
    {
        return view("layouts\masterLayout");
    }
```

Can someone please explain why does that happen?

Comment: You cannot set the namespace for views

Comment: @laravellevaral Ohk. Can you please guide me to some resource stating the reasons for the same.

Comment: Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-view) doc for details of helper function.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views

Comment: Thank you @Easy Sam

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
public function dashboard()
        {
            return view("layouts.masterLayout");
        }
```

Comment: I am looking out to use a namespace and not the name of the folder. `layouts\masterLayout` is same as 'layouts.masterLayout' in Blade.

Comment: Can i assume you want to access view of layout folder's masterlayout page??

Comment: `resources->views->layouts->masterLayout.php`

Comment: want to access masterlayout??

Comment: Yup but I was trying to mention a namespace for that instead of using a folder name in the controller function which as stated by fellow members is not the case. But thanks for the help.

Comment: you can't directly access view in laravel using namespace.

Answer (score 0):

check for views and Views (Capital V in Views)

Answer (score 0):

No need to define namespace for view.Simply use this:

```
return view("layouts.masterLayout");
```